# python e excel(fazendo automação)

Tags: python, microsoft-excel

este códgo abaixo ele pega dados de uma planilha e joga em uma lista depois quero que os dados desta lista  joga em outra planilha.

Até a lista conseguir mas na hora de passar para outra planilha  não sei como fazer.. alguem poderia me ajudar

```py
#coding:latin-1
import xlrd
from openpyxl import workbook
from openpyxl import open
from openpyxl import load_workbook
book=load_workbook("zanlorenzi.xlsx")


from openpyxl import Workbook


arquivo = xlrd.open_workbook('exp.xlsx')
planilha = arquivo.sheet_by_index(0)

lista_valores = planilha.col_values(0)


       #inicio do programa

def xlread(arq_xls):
    #  abre o arquivo para leitura
    xls = xlrd.open_workbook(arq_xls)
    # pega a primeira linha do arquivo
    plan = xls.sheets()[0]
    for i in range(0,plan.nrows):

      yield plan.row_values(i)


zanlorezi=[]

for i in xlread("exp.xlsx"):
    zanlorezi.append(i)
    #for a in zanlorezi:
        #print(zanlorezi)

for i in xlread("zanlorenzi.xlsx"):
     book=

    #print(i)
     book.save("zanlorenzi.xlsx")
for a in zanlorezi:

    print(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ob = wb.get_sheet_by_name('xXx')
ob['c1'] = 'PYTHON' #<:--- 
ob['c1'].value
```

a coordenada da célula  pode ser usada como chave
de dicionário no objeto Worksheet para escrever em cada célula

Comment: obrigado so não entendi porrque "#<"

Comment: posso usar dentro da chave do dicionario no objeto worksheet colocar uma variavel?

Comment: indiquei com uma seta seta  para o dicionario, a chave e o atributo. Cada chave tera que possui um nome unico e individual e o atributo pode ser repetido :)